# R - ggpairs() vs. ggcorr()

Tags: r, ggally, ggpairs, ggcorrplot

I used ggpairs to show the correlation between 10 parameters and it came out nicely. However, when I tried using ggcorr, only a few correlation number showed up, which the results were similar to using cor().

I wonder what are the differences between the calculation method between ggpairs and ggcorr?

[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please be more specific with examples and data? It's going to be easier to help.

Comment: Added the example results.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without reproducible example, but both methods rely on the same defaults: pairwise and pearson. So if you are not changing those defaults it should give similar findings. For displaying coefficients, ggcorr rounds to 1 decimal and ggpairs rounds to 3. Specifying ggcorr to round to three digits gives the same result:

```
ggcorr(iris, label = TRUE, label_round = 3)
ggpairs(iris)
```